# GLESRender Debug Draw on Cocos2d v2.0

Tags: debugging, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, draw

I recently upgraded to cocos2d v2.0 and box2d 2.1.2 and my debug draw stopped working.  The game still works fine but the bodies are not being drawn anymore.  Ive read it has something to do with the fact that cocos2d v2.0 uses GLES 2.0 but nobody has been able to give me a solution, the forums have not responded.

Chipmunk debugdraw also broke but I got a CPDebugLayer class file and i restored it.  Box2d is the only one I've been unable to get working properly.

Anybody run into the same situation?

Comment: Same issue here, I up voted hopefully to get an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

First, install the cocos2d 2.0 templates in the usual way:

```
./install-templates.sh -f
```

Then create a new cocos2d with Box2D project from the template. Replace your project's GLES-Render.h/.m files with the ones from the cocos2d+Box2D template project. That should be all.

It's worth mentioning that if you did any custom OpenGL drawing in your app, you will have to modify the rendering code to use OpenGL ES 2.0 functions exclusively, even if the old code still compiles. Some OpenGL ES 1.1 functions are still available and you can use them, but they usually don't work or worse cause OpenGL errors. That can have a variety of rendering side-effects.